# How to control which column spanned by a long \multicolumn gets the extra space?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have a table that looks something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l r@{\thinspace}d r@{\thinspace}d r@{\thinspace}d}
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Special Programs} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Equipment Maintenance} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{General} \\
  \cmidrule{2-7}
  Category 1 & \$ & 15.25 &    &      &    &        \\
  Category 2 &    & 25.34 &    &      & \$ &  73.00 \\
  Category 3 &    &       & \$ & 5.15 &    & 128.16 \\
  \cmidrule{3-3} \cmidrule{5-5} \cmidrule{7-7}
  Totals     & \$ & 40.59 & \$ & 5.15 & \$ & 201.16 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

That gives me results like the following:

[image]

I'm using separate columns for the dollar signs and the amounts so that the top and bottom dollar signs will always line up.  Unfortunately, when the two-column headers are wider than the columns below them, the extra space is added to the amount column, which puts rather a lot of space between the dollar sign and amount.

Is there a way to reformat things so that the dollar signs are no more than a `\thinspace` away from the left side of the amount texts?

I do have a strong preference for letting LaTeX manage the width of the columns overall, so I'd prefer not to do anything that involves hardcoding column widths anywhere.  (Among other things, all of the table contents--amounts, categories, and column names--are dynamic.  I would like a solution I can put into the generating program once and not have to fine-tune for each separate dataset.)

Comment: To answer the title question, the last column always gets the extra space.

Comment: And there's no way to give the extra space to any column other than the last one?

Comment: Not automatically.  You can always adjust the widths manually using \makebox.

Comment: That wouldn't be great for this project, unfortunately, since the goal is to generate the reports automatically without needing manual layout tweaks.  It looks like the `siunitx` solution from @leandriis will give the best results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `siunitx` package can align numbers with respect to the decimal separator and keep units in the same column. In the second table I have also used the `makecell` package to introduce linebreaks in the long column headers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\dollar}{\$}

\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{table-space-text-pre=\si{\dollar}, table-align-text-pre=true}
\begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=3.2]}
  \toprule
  & {Special Programs} &{Equipment Maintenance} & {General} \\
  \cmidrule{2-4}
  Category 1 & \si{\dollar} 15.25 &                   &        \\
  Category 2 &             25.34  &                   & \si{\dollar}  73.00 \\
  Category 3 &                    & \si{\dollar} 5.15 &              128.16 \\
  \cmidrule(r){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(l){4-4}
  Totals     & \si{\dollar} 40.59 & \si{\dollar} 5.15 & \si{\dollar}  201.16 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=3.2]}
  \toprule
  & {\makecell{Special\\ Programs}} &{\makecell{Equipment\\ Maintenance}} & {General} \\
  \cmidrule{2-4}
  Category 1 & \si{\dollar} 15.25 &                   &        \\
  Category 2 &             25.34  &                   & \si{\dollar}  73.00 \\
  Category 3 &                    & \si{\dollar} 5.15 &              128.16 \\
  \cmidrule(r){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(l){4-4}
  Totals     & \si{\dollar} 40.59 & \si{\dollar} 5.15 & \si{\dollar}  201.16 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```